# Diophantine-like Equation

Tags: quartics

Is there a neat method for solving equations of the form:
$$\frac {a^2}{x^2}-\frac {b^2}{(1-x)^2}=c^2$$
where $0<x<1$, by exploiting the symmetry in instead of expanding it as a fully-blown quartic?

Perhaps one could use the substitution $y=\frac 12-x$, but it doesn't seem to go far.

---

Additional Note: The original equation has
$$\begin{align}
a^2&=u^2\mu^2\\ b^2&=v^2(1-\mu)^2\\ c^2&=\frac {v^2-u^2}{\gamma^2}\end{align}$$
where $0<\mu <1$. Note sure if this additional information helps.

Comment: What restrictions (if any) are there on the values of $a, b, c$, and $x$?

Comment: @paw88789 have edited to specify that $0<x<1$, and added some notes on the constants.

Comment: Worth trying to find geometric or physical model.

Comment: If $0<x<1$, why have you tagged this "diophantine equations"?  Are you looking for solutions in rational $x$?

Comment: @AdamBailey - There isn't a tag for diophantine-like, and perhaps even that is not suitable. Please change the tag to a more appropriate one.

Answer (score 2):

Above equation shown below:

$$\frac {a^2}{x^2}-\frac {b^2}{(1-x)^2}=c^2\tag1$$

Equation $(1)$ is actually a hyperbolic curve in disguise.

Taking, $x=(\cos p)^2$ we get $(1-x)=(\sin p)^2$.

For p=30 degree's we get, $(\sin p)^2 =\frac14$ &

$x=(\cos p)^2=\frac34$

Thus we get equation:

$$(4a)^2=(12b)^2+(3c)^2\tag2$$
Equation $(2)$ is satisfied at,

$(a,b,c)=[((5/4),(1/4),(4/3)]$

Hence solution for equation $(1)$:

$(a,b,c,x)=[((5/4),(1/4),(4/3),(3/4)]$

Comment: Thanks for your solution (+1). For the original question, $a,b,c$ are given, so the objective is to express $x$ in terms of $a,b,c$. However, a closed-form solution might not exist for the general case.